# Where to find the Package Installation Wizard in VS2008 for Deploying SSIS Package?

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, deployment, ssis

This is probably a dumb question, but my brain is just about fried for the day.

Where do I find the Package Installation Wizard in VS2008 to deploy my SSIS Package?

Answer (score 1):

DTSInstall.exe is the executable that is the SSIS Package Installation Wizard/[Deployment Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141693.aspx). It should be found at

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTSInstall.exe`

You can also automate deploys by using PowerShell and the SSIS APIs as I demonstrate on [PowerShell SSIS deployment and maintenance](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/08/powershell-ssis-deployment-and.html)

Comment: When I click that exe, I get the error - You need to specify the full path to a SSIS deployment manifest file. That is because I SSIS does not create a manifest, despite doing all the right things. Can you help me with that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146890/ssis-wont-generate-deployment-files