# SSIS won't generate deployment files

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I enabled building of deployment by - MySolution > right click > properties > CreateDeploymentUtility = True, DeploymentOutputPath = bin\Deployment > Apply > OK.

Then, SSIS > Build > Build MySolution.

I went to the above folder (under visual studio 2008 projects) and saw nothing there. why is this happening and how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without the deployment utility also. Steps -

SSIS server deployment -

Connect to your SSIS server inside SSMS > Stored Packages > File System > Import package > *Now import YourPackage as desired*.

YourPackage > right click > Run package > Configurations tab > *Fetch your config file and put it here*

OR ,

SQL server deployment -

Connect to your SQL server inside SSMS > SQL server agent > Jobs > New Job > Steps option > type = s-s-i-s package > general tab: package source = file system > configurations tab: Add...etc.

Answer (score -2):

Did the build succeed?  You can click on the solution in the Solution Explorer and navigate to the path shown in FullPath.  That is where the bin folder will be.

Comment: Build occurs with no errors and no warnings. I saw no deployment folder in the bin folder (of full path).